# Bind datagridcell to display content of a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to display the content of a collection in a datagrid cell. What is special, is that the columnheaders are bound to a specific item of collection (i.e. one for each workday). The cell content should be a textbox for each employee in the according collection. The columnheaderpart is working fine.

The hierarchy of the viewmodel is as follows:

```
Planning holds a collection of Projects and a collection of Days(used to get the columnheader)
Project holds a collection of Days
Day holds a collection of Employees
```

However, the following code is not working. From debugging I'm lead to believe that the it is a problem with binding, as there is no access to the employees collection. Any idea why this is not working?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Planning.Projects}" ColumnHeaderHeight="50">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Project" Binding="{Binding Projectname}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Week.Days[0].Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=ddd}"/>
                    <LineBreak/>            
                    <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Planning.Projects.Days[0].Employees}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>                                
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: OK, so the `DataContext` for the Cell `DataTemplate` is probably one instance of `Project`, because the `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` is a collection called `Projects`. Confirm this by *temporarily* replacing the template content with `<Label Content="{Binding}" />`, it'll probably give you the fully resolved classname of `Project`. OK. So that's the `DataContext`, almost certainly. Hence, in the `CellTemplate`, any `Path` on a `Binding` is resolved as a property of a `Project`. So this should work: `<ItemsConttrol ItemsSource="{Binding Days[0].Employees}">`.

Comment: My concern is this: `DataContext.Planning.Projects.Days[0].Employees`. There's a lot in that path that could be the result of a misconception about how data contexts work, but could also be a product of some unconventional choices in viewmodel design. Does `Project` have a `DataContext` property? I'd advise against using that as a viewmodel property name. I'm not sure what to make of `Projects.Days` either; isn't `Projects` a generic collection? I would hope it is `ObservableCollection<Project>`.

Comment: You were right: `<ItemsConttrol ItemsSource="{Binding Days[0].Employees}"`works fine. I don't understand it though, as the path is the same to me. 
As to your second remark: yes, I used a an `ObservableCollection`. Where as the naming was translated from German, where it is more precise.
I agree, the design is unconventional, but I'm fairly new to this, and the task of "transposing" the days collection in order to display it in a weekly view.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` has no property named `Days`.

Comment: The projects class has a propety Days which is `ObservableCollection<Days>`

Comment: You tried to bind to `Planning.Projects.Days`. What is `Projects`? `Projects` is a property of `Planning`. What data type is `Projects`? You're using it like a collection, so I think it's a collection. Is it a subclass of a regular generic collection?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! You're right, projects is a regular type `ObservableCollection` of a class called project. This collection is a property of Planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` for the Cell `DataTemplate` is probably one instance of `Project`, because the `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` is a collection called `Projects`.

Therefore, in the `CellTemplate`, any `Path` on a `Binding` should be referring to a property of a `Project`, just as in the `Projectname` column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Width="200" 
    Header="Project" 
    Binding="{Binding Projectname}">
```

`Project` is the `DataContext` for each column. The above `Binding` works because `Projectname` is a property of `Project`.

So this should work:

```
<ItemsConttrol 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Days[0].Employees}"
    ...
```

`Project` has a `Days` collection. You want the `Employees` collection from the first item in `Days` for this project.